# Transfering audio files from android phone to a website

Tags: android

I want to send a recorded audio file from an android phone to a website. No wires are to be used, this has to be  done in the phone. How can I achieve this? What APIs should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Try HttpManager and POST upload request.

Comment: Can u please be more specific? can u give me some links?

Comment: There were pretty much similar questions already. Try the http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+upload search request. I'm pretty sure you'll find what you need.